# I am getting errors such as " braced block of statements is an unused closure" and expected expression

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

This is my first time doing a simple project in swift and these errors are bugging me for last couple of hours. I have this code below and even though i have curly braces around and statements inside the if/else i still get that errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated guys.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var `switch`: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet var Answer: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var tempInput: UITextField!


    //aqnswer value

    @IBAction func switchPressed(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        if switch.on {

            self.Answer.text = "cel to fah"
        }
        else {

            self.Answer.text = "fah to cel"
        }

    }
        //textfield value



    @IBAction func calculate(sender: AnyObject)
            {
                //get user input 
                // value = celcius

                 var Value:Int = tempInput.text.toInt()!

                var toFah :Int = ( 32 + Value * 9 ) / 5

                //to celcius

                var toCel: Int = (Value-32) * 5 / 9

                if switch.on {



                    self.Answer.text = toFah.description
                }

                else {
                self.Answer.text = toCel.description
                }






               // println(fah)

               // Answer.text = fah.description


                }



    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Please include which errors you are getting and at which linesbthey are at.

Comment: ok so i inserted parenthsis around the switch.on statement and now it says expected , seperator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Swift Language Guide says:

> If you need to give a constant or variable the same name as a reserved
>   Swift keyword, surround the keyword with back ticks (`) when using it
>   as a name. However, **avoid using keywords as names unless you have
>   absolutely no choice**.

In your example you have indeed a choice…

But if you really really really want to use `switch` as a variable name you have to wrap **all** occurrences of `switch` in back ticks.